# Azure CDN Caching, Images not updating immediately?

Tags: .net, azure, caching, cdn, azure-cdn

I have created a CDN in Azure and I am building a .NET MVC Web Application that has the capability to upload an image to the CDN.

The initial upload works great and the image is available immediately after uploading.

If I upload again, with a different image, it does not update immediately from the web application. However, in my Azure portal, I can open the storage account container and see the new file available immediately.

No matter how much I refresh or restart the web application, it does not see the image until 5-10 minutes after the updated image upload.

It appears to me that this is something to do with the CDN caching in Azure. I have been searching for a solution for the past couple hours, and it seems there is very little documentation available online for this particular problem (which is strange, there is no way I am the first to have this problem, right?).

Also, under the Caching Rules in the CDN Endpoint in Azure, I can only see one drop down instead of the multitude of options I have seen elsewhere online, and none of the options seem to allow me to disable caching.

So, how can I get the updated images to display immediately?

Thanks!!

EDIT:

Here is the solution that is currently working for me:

Create all images with a GUID as the name. When a user uploads a new image, delete the old one, and upload the new one with a different GUID. Since they have different names, the CDN caching does not interfere.

Comment: CDN has a time-to-live (TTL). What is your TTL set at? New content won't be seen until the TTL expires.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am not sure. I can't seem to find it anywhere in Azure and there isn't really any documentation on how to find/set it. I am also not sure if I need to be doing something with cache-control headers or query string versioning? Could you explain more about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not an uncommon problem at all.

Check the value of the query string caching behaviour in the caching rules for your endpoint.  If you serve the uploaded images on a URL that uses a query string param configure the cache to cache every unique url (rather than the bypassing or ignoring query string options).  Think of this as the key to where the value is your image binary.

Next check that the origin is serving the HTTP Headers that you expect (expires, max-age, etag and cache-control as appropriate) and that they have values appropriate for your content.

Also investigate the purge API.  If your initial resource exists in the CDN you may need to call the purge API if the user's upload would create the same key.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing the **browser cache**. You can reload the site and the cache using <kbd>STRG</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or use a different browser to ensure the image is updated within the CDN.

A solution would be to add a query parameter to your image. E. g. `https://yourdomain/storage/tmp.img?version=1234` Then you can update the version which will force the browsers to reload the image (but this would require a redeploy of your app).

Comment: If they have a TTL set, longer than they're currently waiting (and refreshing the browser), then refreshing the browser won't matter.

Comment: @DavidMakogon True, that could also be the case!

Comment: I just double checked and this is definitely not a browser caching issue. I also cannot redeploy my application every time a user uploads an image...